# Stuck up with JAXB - unmarshal XML exception

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Can any one help me to get out of this exception.

> unexpected element (uri:"http://cpps.xxx.com/splm-service",
>   local:"PartInquiryService"). Expected elements are (none)

Here is the code and xml i am using

```
 File file = new File("PartInquiryService.xml");
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PartInquiryService.class);
 Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
 PartInquiryService partInqService =
         (PartInquiryService)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Here is the xml am using it ..I will be getting this xml as a response from MQ

```
<PartInquiryService xmlns="http://cpps.xxx.com/splm-service" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <control>
    <type>inquiryWithServiceWindow</type>
    <correlationId format="hex">A10488237F3B7734A10488237F3B7734A10488237F3B7734</correlationId>
    <origin>
      <system>CPPS-SPLM</system>
      <id>MP2ZCP5</id>
      <at timeZone="UTC">
        <date format="ISO">2008-12-12</date>
        <time format="ISO">20:12:48</time>
      </at>
    </origin>
    <destination>
      <system>SPLM_GUI</system>
      <id>SPLM_01</id>
    </destination>
  </control>
  <partInquiry>
    <customerSystemkey>123456789123456</customerSystemkey>
    <countryCode type="IBM">788</countryCode>
    <partnumber>0000039M5123</partnumber>
    <machType>1722</machType>
    <zipcode>1066 VH</zipcode>
  </partInquiry>
  <inquiryResult>
    <errorMessage>Invalid part number XXXXXXXXXXXX received</errorMessage>
    <zipcodeUsed>NL 1066</zipcodeUsed>
    <timeZone>MSK</timeZone>
    <currency>EUR</currency>
    <partnumber>
      <id>0000039M5123</id>
      <subType>REQ</subType>
      <description>POWER CORD</description>
      <subRank>0</subRank>
      <weigth>10</weigth>
      <length>12</length>
      <width>9</width>
      <height>11</height>
      <sellingPrice currency="EUR">12.030</sellingPrice>
      <rohsInd>C</rohsInd>
    </partnumber>
    <partnumber>
      <id>0000040K8888</id>
      <subType>ALT</subType>
      <description>POWER CORD</description>
      <subRank>0</subRank>
      <weigth>10</weigth>
      <length>12</length>
      <width>9</width>
      <height>11</height>
      <sellingPrice currency="EUR">12.030</sellingPrice>
      <rohsInd>D</rohsInd>
    </partnumber>
    <partnumber>
      <id>0000012J1234</id>
      <subType>SUB</subType>
      <description>POWER CORD</description>
      <subRank>-1</subRank>
      <weigth>10</weigth>
      <length>12</length>
      <width>9</width>
      <height>11</height>
      <sellingPrice currency="EUR">12.030</sellingPrice>
      <rohsInd>N</rohsInd>
    </partnumber>
    <sourceLocation>
      <locId>788-5000</locId>
      <description>CENTRAL BUFFER VENLO</description>
      <deliveryOption>
        <serviceWindow>Sameday 2hr</serviceWindow>
        <logisticCost>88.00</logisticCost>
        <date format="ISO">2014-08-24</date>
        <time format="ISO">10:56:00</time>
      </deliveryOption>
      <deliveryOption>
        <serviceWindow>Next day 16:00</serviceWindow>
        <logisticCost>10.00</logisticCost>
        <date format="ISO">2014-08-25</date>
        <time format="ISO">16:00:00</time>
      </deliveryOption>
      <partInventory>
        <id>0000039M5123</id>
        <availableStock>1</availableStock>
      </partInventory>
      <partInventory>
        <id>0000040K8888</id>
        <availableStock>5</availableStock>
      </partInventory>
    </sourceLocation>
    <sourceLocation>
      <locId>821-9200</locId>
      <description>CRS ST PETERSBURG</description>
      <deliveryOption>
        <serviceWindow>Sameday 2hr</serviceWindow>
        <logisticCost>88.00</logisticCost>
        <date format="ISO">2014-08-24</date>
        <time format="ISO">10:56:00</time>
      </deliveryOption>
      <deliveryOption>
        <serviceWindow>Next day 16:00</serviceWindow>
        <logisticCost>10.00</logisticCost>
        <date format="ISO">2014-08-25</date>
        <time format="ISO">16:00:00</time>
      </deliveryOption>
      <partInventory>
        <id>0000039M5123</id>
        <availableStock>1</availableStock>
      </partInventory>
      <partInventory>
        <id>0000040K8888</id>
        <availableStock>5</availableStock>
      </partInventory>
    </sourceLocation>
    <sourceLocation>
      <locId>821-1102</locId>
      <description>LSH MOSCOW DUTY PAID</description>
      <deliveryOption>
        <serviceWindow>Sameday 2hr</serviceWindow>
        <logisticCost>88.00</logisticCost>
        <date format="ISO">2014-08-24</date>
        <time format="ISO">10:56:00</time>
      </deliveryOption>
      <deliveryOption>
        <serviceWindow>Next day 16:00</serviceWindow>
        <logisticCost>10.00</logisticCost>
        <date format="ISO">2014-08-25</date>
        <time format="ISO">16:00:00</time>
      </deliveryOption>
      <partInventory>
        <id>0000039M5123</id>
        <availableStock>1</availableStock>
      </partInventory>
      <partInventory>
        <id>0000040K8888</id>
        <availableStock>5</availableStock>
      </partInventory>
    </sourceLocation>
  </inquiryResult>
</PartInquiryService>
```

Here is the PartInquiryService.java

```
public class PartInquiryService {
    private Control control;
    private PartInquiry partInqury;
    private InquiryResult inquiryResult;
    public Control getControl() {
        return control;
    }
    public void setControl(Control control) {
        this.control = control;
    }
    public PartInquiry getPartInqury() {
        return partInqury;
    }
    public void setPartInqury(PartInquiry partInqury) {
        this.partInqury = partInqury;
    }
    public InquiryResult getInquiryResult() {
        return inquiryResult;
    }
    public void setInquiryResult(InquiryResult inquiryResult) {
        this.inquiryResult = inquiryResult;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show us PartInquiryService.class?

Comment: Hi Xstian, thanks for your reply, i have added the code snippet for PartInquiryService ?I have created other .java binding files which are used in the xml unmarshalling i.e Control.java,PartInquiry.java etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add on your class `PartInquiryService.java`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PartInquiryService" ,namespace="http://cpps.xxx.com/splm-service")
public class PartInquiryService {
```

in the same package put this class (`package-info.java`)

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://cpps.xxx.com/splm-service", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package your.package;
```

**Note:** the namespace within @XmlRootElement is no necessary in this case but I used to reinforce this information.

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you :)

Comment: Hi Xstian , hope we can even use the below command to generate all the JAXB classes  , by running this command ... $xjc xx-xx-xx-xxx.xsd -p <package> -d C:/<directory> ?

Comment: Hi @chandiprasad I usually used `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to generate java classes from XSD that generates also package-info.java, anyway, Yes you can and, I think that if you add -npa on your command should be works fine. [see this reference](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html).

Comment: It is always a pleasure :) .. however [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26337220/3364187) to get ideas of plugin.